# Error result using New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport - Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource

Tags: azure

I am trying to use the New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport in the powershell since the Continuous Export feature is currently not available unless we migrate the current resource for application insight in workspace-based application resource. Unfortunately we do not have the authority to do it for now so thats why we are using the alternative method through powershell. I followed the instructions and created the sample storage creation found in the document of microsoft. Then after that used the sample command "**New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport**". Did change the value based on the settings we have and execute it. But I encountered an error which is "*Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource*". Been trying to find how to solve but unfortunately, I am stuck. Would someone help or direct me what should I do on this? Thanks! I posted the image of the command i executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CzoR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0P3D.png)

I tried different approach of values that on the parameters that I think might work but its not working also. I also checked the "appinsighttest1" storage account configuration that was created by checking the settings, network, keys and other that might enable/visible for the command to work. My idea is the reason that it is not found maybe i have to enable something the storage account configuration. But right now i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> Error result using New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport - Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource:

**"Parent resource 'test' not found:**  It means that no application insight resource with the name *"test"* has been created in Azure. You must first create an application insight in Azure Portal before using `New-AzApplicationInsightContinuousexport`.

*I created in my environment as shown:*

[image]

Using [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/new-azapplicationinsightscontinuousexport?view=azps-9.2.0#example-1-create-a-new-continuous-export-configuration-for-an-application-insights-resource) as a reference, I tried in my environment with few modifications and successfully enabled continuous export with the respective command.

***Script to run:***

```
$context = $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxxstorageaccountname" -StorageAccountKey "xxxStorageaccountkey=="
$sastn = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name <container> -Context  $context -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddYears(50) -Permission w
$SASuri = "https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>" + $sastn
New-AzApplicationInsightsContinuousExport -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<applicationinsightname>" -DocumentType "Request","Trace", "Custom Event" -StorageAccountId "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourcegroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storageaccount>" -StorageLocation EastUS -StorageSASUri $SASuri -DestinationType Blob
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Note***: ***This error might occur when you do not have enough right (access) to give/modify the permissions or roles.*** ***Assign "Storage Blob Data Owner" role for the storage account.***

Comment: Hi Jahnavi, Thanks for the response! I appreciate it. I followed your instruction. Created an application insight resource (this is the missing step I did last time) then added the Storage Blob Data Owner in the Access Control (IAM) in the storage account. Then re-executed the command line following how you detailed it above. But this time i am getting a new error. which is : "The server responded with a Request Error, Status: BadRequest". Can you share what other steps did you make in your environment that when you execute it, it is successfull.

Comment: Checked the activity logs with the message error below. I am thinking maybe an issue with my account level? : 
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "BadRequest",
        "localizedValue": "Bad Request (HTTP Status Code: 400)"
    },
    "properties": {
        "statusCode": "BadRequest",
        "serviceRequestId": null,
        "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"\"}}",
        "eventCategory": "Administrative",
        "entity": "/subscriptions/xxxx...",
        "message": "microsoft.insights/components/exportconfiguration/action",
    },

Comment: Thank You @Dondon. Yes, you need to have "owner" role for the subscription to avoid this error. Can you give a try in windows PowerShell ISE by "Run as Administrator"!

Comment: Most likely my account level. I am actually using the bult in browser powershell in the azure. So i tried the PowerShell ISE in my desktop as you indicated and run as an administrator. Executed first the command "Add-AzureAccount" and it returns that no subscriptions with the logged account in RDFE. That my account is not an admin or co admin. But will try the Connect-AzureRMAccount. Will give you an update for this. :)